# jQuery simplest way to add one symbol to a <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I need to add the '%' symbol to the HTML value of a span.

```
var html = $('#spanId').html() + '%';
$('#spanId').html(html);
```

It works, but looks really ugly. Is there a simpler way to code this?

Comment: $('#spanId').append('%');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#spanId').append('%');`, as MidoDev said.

Answer (score 1):

You can find different ways, for example:

```
$('#spanId').append('%');
```

or

```
$('#spanId').html($('#spanId').html() + '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5Rs7p/)***

The `text` method would probably be best for this. In jQuery, almost every method accepts a callback, and in that callback, the current element is `this`. So you could simply use a return as such:

```
$('#spanId').text(function(){
 return this.innerHTML + "%";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#spanId').html( $('#spanId').html()+'%' );
```